# get last value from JSON array

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a JSON string within a MySQL database which I could like to get 2 numbers from within WordPress.

My string is as follows:

```
a:1:{i:300;a:4:{s:7:"lessons";a:1:{i:302;i:1;}s:6:"topics";a:1:{i:302;a:2:{i:304;i:1;i:311;i:1;}}s:9:"completed";i:1;s:5:"total";i:4;}}
```

The `i:300` is the course ID. Within the `topics` is both `302` and `311`. These are the IDs of each page completed. I need to get the last one of these which in this case would be `311`.

I basically need something that would do the following:

Get Page ID
Find Page ID in JSON string
Get the last ID from JSON string topics

How would I go about this?

**Update - Getting the string from the DB but doesn't display.**

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$sql1 = "SELECT meta_value FROM xrji_usermeta";
$sql3 = " WHERE user_id = ".$user_id." AND meta_key = '_sfwd-course_progress';";
$sql =  $sql1 . "" . $sql3;
//echo "sql: ".$sql;
$a = $conn->query($sql);
$results = unserialize($a);
echo "<br>results: ".$results;
```

I have the above however nothing is shown for `$results` however if I run the query through sequel pro it works fine.

```
SELECT meta_value FROM xrji_usermeta WHERE user_id = 2 AND meta_key = '_sfwd-course_progress'
```

Comment: print_r(unserialize($str));

Comment: This JSON is invalid

Comment: This string is serialized array. First you need to [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it; that access it as ordinary array; [demo](https://eval.in/601791).

Comment: @mulquin That's because it's not JSON to begin with...

Comment: Is your serialised string actually pretty-printed like that? Because then it's not de-serialisable and broken.

Comment: This is what I get from the database: a:1:{i:300;a:4:{s:7:"lessons";a:1:{i:302;i:1;}s:6:"topics";a:1:{i:302;a:2:{i:304;i:1;i:311;i:1;}}s:9:"completed";i:1;s:5:"total";i:4;}}

Comment: Have you tried putting that into `unserialize()` as @glavic has suggested? You generally can't do much with serialized strings until you decode them into objects.

Comment: I have updated my question. so my understanding would be to unserialize the output and then get the last value from the topics array?

Comment: This is the output (also shown in Galvic demo): Array ( [300] => Array ( [lessons] => Array ( [302] => 1 ) [topics] => Array ( [302] => Array ( [304] => 1 [311] => 1 ) ) [completed] => 1 [total] => 4 ) )

Comment: Great, your got an array, now use [`array_pop()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)  to get last value of the needed array.

Comment: @Glavić How would I use array_pop()? Not sure how to take my output to get the number 311 in this instance?

Comment: Do you want the last key from the array  `$array[300][topics][302]` ?

Comment: @BenH We have shown you how to get an actual array from your serialised string. Do you know how to work with arrays...?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with arrays as a whole. More so with nested arrays. from the unserialized output I would need to get the last topic KEY so in the output shown it owuld be the number 311 so yes that is correct @splash58

Comment: `$t = array_keys($array[300]['topics'][302]); echo end($t);`

Comment: full code - https://eval.in/601839

Comment: I won't have access to the 302 ID value because I will be within the id 300. So I basically need the last key from the last topic array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you posted is not a JSON, it's a result of **PHP serialization** that is done through [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) function.

In order to use the values, you have to get this string and pass to the [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) function, which will give you... well, it will give you an error:

**PHP Notice:  unserialize(): Error at offset 5 of 235 bytes**

That's because you assumed it was JSON and formatted it for us. It's okay for JSON and death to serialized string. You need to get rid of whitespaces:

'a:1:{i:300;a:4:{s:7:"lessons";a:1:{i:302;i:1;}s:6:"topics";a:1:{i:302;a:2:{i:304;i:1;i:311;i:1;}}s:9:"completed";i:1;s:5:"total";i:4;}}'

After you do `unserialize()` on it, you will get:

```
Array
(
    [300] => Array
        (
            [lessons] => Array
                (
                    [302] => 1
                )

            [topics] => Array
                (
                    [302] => Array
                        (
                            [304] => 1
                            [311] => 1
                        )

                )

            [completed] => 1
            [total] => 4
        )
)
```

So, you get a PHP array in $a and now you can do whatever you want with it:

```
$courseID = 300;
$lessons = array_keys($a[$courseID]['lessons']);
$topics = array_keys($a[$courseID]['topics']);
$pages = array_keys($a[$courseID]['topics'][ $topics[0] ]);
$lastPage = $pages[ count($pages)-1 ];
```

You will have 302 in $topics, 304 and 311 in $pages and 311 in $lastPage.

**Sidenote: How to distinguish JSON from PHP serialization**

This is a bit of a simplification, but it's good for memorization. Whenever I see a bunch of `<one-letter>:<number>:<value>` periods, I assume that it's the serialization result, where `<one-letter>` is type (**a**rray, **s**tring, **i**nteger) and `<number>` is a length in characters or array elements (omitted for integer). If instead of `<one-letter>` I see descriptive variable names, enclosed in `"quotation_marks"`, or arrays that are wrapped in `[square brackets]`, I assume it's JSON.

Comment: I'm not allowed to chime in to the long discussion in the comments to your question, but please try the code I described here, it seems to have solved your problem.

Comment: I have a query to get the string from the database and if i run the query within sequel pro it works fine however when running through PHP i get zero output. I have updated my question with the code. Would you mind taking a look? Thanks

Comment: @BenH, after $conn->query() line, add `$result = $a->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);` and then `var_dump($result);`